# a forking service blocks ssh connection even if the main process ends

Tags: python, ssh, tcp, sshd, setsid

I have a program that should be run from `sshd`. It should print few lines to stdout and then fork and exit. The forked program should do its stuff detached from `sshd` without blocking the program.  The thing is that the program below runs correctly when executed from a terminal shell or via ssh with option `-t`. It blocks ssh connection when the terminal is not assigned.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os, time, sys

print("Hello world", flush=True)
if os.fork()==0:
    # child
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr.close()
    os.setsid()
    # just in case make a second fork
    if os.fork()>0:
        os.exit()
    os.setsid()
    time.sleep(30)
    os.exit(0)
os.wait()
print("bye, world")
```

How can I make the program release ssh connection even if invoked without terminal?

1. Direct run (runs correctly, exits immediately leaving forked child):

```bash
./test-prog.py
```

2. Via ssh with forced terminal still works correctly:

```bash
ssh -t server ./test-prog.py
```

3. Via ssh without forced terminal doesn't work correctly. It prints both lines and then waits 30 seconds to release ssh:

```bash
ssh server ./test-prog.py
```

I would run this program from a daemon connecting via ssh and exit leaving forked child detached from ssh.
In real application this program just opens few tcp socket and writes their port number on stdout. The client reads the ports and then connects to it.

Comment: In this case, OpenSSH sshd would close the exec channel when it sees end-of-file on the pipe which it created for test-prog.py's standard output. If you check the file descriptors held open by this child process, you may find that it still has a pipe open to the sshd process somehow.

Comment: @Kenster… But you can see, that I close all descriptors just after the fork().

Comment: Never, ever, close (and leave closed) stdin/stdout/stderr. Any subsequent opens will be assigned those file descriptors. Any code that then writes to stdout/stderr will be writing to an unexpected destination. Always reopen those file descriptors on */dev/null*.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in python `sys.stdin.close()` doesn't really close fd 0, neither does closing `stdout` and `stderr` close fd 1 and 2.

ssh keeps the connection if:

1. the pty is open *or*
2. all fds 0,1,2 (and perhaps other passed using `-L` and `-R` options) are closed if there is no pty allocated, i.e. there is no pty in calling process and no `-t` option to ssh.

So the correct way to close standard streams is to `dup2` them to `/dev/null`, for instance with the following code:

```py
import os
if os.fork()==0:
  # child
  f_in = open("/dev/null")
  f_out = open("/dev/null,"w")
  os.dup2( f_in.fileno(), 0)
  os.dup2( f_out.fileno(), 1)
  os.dup2( 1, 2)
```